# Extra-long Power Adapter Extension Cable Wanted

Tags: power, apple

> The 1.8-meter [Power Adapter Extension Cable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/388894/150109) is an AC extension cord that provides extra length for your Apple power adapter. Use it with MagSafe and MagSafe 2 power adapters.

From [Apple's page on it](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK122LL/A/power-adapter-extension-cable?fnode=8b).

The only official cord seems to be a 1.8-meter long cable.

Can someone please help me find a much longer version, I am imagining about 5 metres?

I would like one for the UK please. The reason I want one instead of a traditional extension cable, and plugging my charger into that, is so that I can transport it more easily and have less cables and less cable connections to worry about.

Comment: If you need to extend the AC side, why does a regular power extension cable not work for you?

Comment: @Romen Fire codes in the US generally prevent the use of two consecutive NEMA 5-15 Male-Female extension cords; might be the same in the UK where the OP is. Maybe they need a longer cable to avoid that, or want a long cable to carry in their laptop bag for convenience?

Comment: @theonlygusti Do you want this for the US or for the UK (Apple part https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/MK122B/A/power-adapter-extension-cable?fnode=85) ? I noticed your spelling of 'metre', and also the time of day you asked, so would like to confirm what you want. That cord looks like it ends in https://imgur.com/a/U2rlIfX a reverse female CEE 7/5 such as was used in France

Answer (score 1):

Both the long cord for the MagSafe and MagSafe 2 power supplied end with a [keyed connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4bix.jpg) I have not been able to find on cables, but it's similar to the [figure 8](https://images.monoprice.com/productlargeimages/76741.jpg) connector plug commonly used with all kinds of radios and other electronic devices, aka Non-Polarized IEC 60320 C7.

So, I tried a 'figure 8' cable. It fits, and works with my MagSafe and circa-2012 Unibody MacBook on US mains power. One such US cord, 5m length, is the https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=7674

For a UK cord, here's a 5m version https://www.newark.com/pro-elec/pel00505/power-cord-uk-iec-60320-c7-5m/dp/07AH4471

And, for reference, the stock Apple power cord for the UK (per a consultation with an Apple Specialist in chat) is 1.8m meter long, the https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/MK122B/A/power-adapter-extension-cable?fnode=85 .

Comment: Please also see https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for the use of the checkmark  (✅) below the arrowheads.

Answer (score 0):

If you were looking at extending the DC end of a power supply (Magsafe, AC adapter, power brick), you would need to worry about the power drop over a greater length of cable. This is not because it's DC but because your electronics use relatively low voltages.

Because you are extending the AC end of your power supply, you are better off with a proper extension cable. In the same way, this is because the AC end is using higher voltages and can travel greater distance without voltage drop.

[This 40ft 16AWG cable](https://smile.amazon.com/Master-Electrician-02356-01ME-40-Feet-Extension/dp/B0039VC672) is rated for 13A at 120V, that is 1560W, while your Magsafe is less than 100W. For this length, 16AWG wire will only see a drop of about a tenth of a volt for 100W of power. That is perfectly fine. You do not want to go less than 16AWG becuase that will limit what else you can do with the cable. Be wary of any cables that do not list what size the cable is. Here is a [similar cable](https://smile.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-Extension-Cord-feet-White/dp/B075BM2H62) if you only want 25ft.

The apple connectors do not specify a size or wire gauge. They are meant to supply little power over short distances. Any off brand products that go longer will probably be cheap small wires and that kind of power drop is not good for your devices or safety. If you plan to run anything heaver than a computer, or run multiple devices, I recommend a 14AWG cable. This is typically what is installed in buildings and will see much less voltage drop.

Note that any "voltage drop" in the cable is heat in the cable. Small cables over long distances are unsafe.

AWG - American Wire Gauge

Comment: The cable linked in question has an american style plug on it. If you are looking for UK cables, please specify which plug. IE: Type G